# record Audio on iOS, and auto save audio every minute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to record audio on iOS, and auto save audio every minute.
the main purpose is not losing the audio after 1 hour record on crash.

Comment: Did you ever solve the auto saving of audio files while recording?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of code to post here  to show you how to record the audio, but there are many examples on GitHub. [Here](http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/) are a [couple](https://github.com/Nitewriter/Breaker-iOS/commits/master/Audio).

To autosave recordings, I would suggest adding a notification timer. [Here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html) is an example.

I hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like audio queues are your best friends are. Read through the doc, it is pretty lucid.